# Find the total number of ordered pairs $(m,n)$ such that $m^2n=20^{20}$ where $m,n$ are positive integers.

Tags: combinatorics

Find the total number of ordered pairs $(m,n)$ such that $m^2n=20^{20}$ where $m,n$ are positive integers.

---

My Approach: Simplifying $$m^2n=20^{20}=(2^2 \times 5)^{20}=2^{40} \times 5^{20}$$
Hence one way is $n=5^{20}, m=2^{20}$ or vice-versa or $m=2^{10},n=10^{20}$ and $m=5^{10},n=4^{20}$. These are the only ways I could think of initially but there are several combinations possible for values of $m,n$. If anyone can help spot a pattern or what are the possible values of $m,n$, I 'll try again to proceed further. I believe that there are many integers possible but I am not able to apply the correct logic.
Thank You.

Comment: Try putting $m = 2^a5^b$ and $n = 2^c5^d$. This will make your job much easier. The point is that $a,b,c,d$ will determine $m,n$, and they can vary relatively freely.

Comment: $m$ can be just an arbitrary divisor of $20^{10}$ (and then $n$ is uniquely determined)

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen, can you please elaborate your point a bit more?

Comment: Yes @TeresaLisbon, got your way of approaching this problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$m^2 n = 2^{40} \times 5^{20}$. We need number of ways to assign values to $m$ and for each $m$, $n$ is fixed.

$m^2 = 2^{2a} \times 5^{2b}$ where $0 \leq 2a \leq 40, 0 \leq2b \leq 20$

$ \implies m = 2^a \times 5^b$ where $0 \leq a \leq 20, 0 \leq b \leq 10$

That gives us $21 \times 11 = 231$ solutions

Comment: Thank you very much @MathLover. Understood your point. I suppose somewhat it considers the point of HagonvonEitzen.

Comment: @PCMSE I just read the comments. Yes it absolutely does. $m = 2^a \times 5^b$ with $a \leq 20, b \leq 10$ are indeed all divisors of $20^{10}$

Comment: I did not work out the details, but my guess is that you can use Euclid's lemma and not the full power the FTA.

Comment: @PCMSE you surely can but have to be more careful in that case. Please note that $20^{20} = 2^{40} \times 5^{20}$ so if we take $n = 2^a \times 5^b$, $a, b$ cannot be odd as that would not leave a square number for $m^2$. So the valid values of $n$ would be with $a = 0, 2, 4, 6, ..40$ and $b = 0, 2, 4, 6, ..20$ and that is again $21 \times 11$

Comment: Okay @MathLover, thank you.

Answer (score 3):

Let $m=2^a5^b$ and $n=2^c5^d$.

So,
\begin{align*}
m^2n&=2^{2a}5^{2b}2^c5^d\\
&=2^{2a+c}5^{2b+d}=2^{40}5^{20}
\end{align*}
which implies
$$2a+c=40\\2b+d=20$$

Since $2a+c=40$, $c$ has to even. So, we can put $c=2,4,6\dots$ and find the corresponding values of $a$. We can do the same for $b$ and $d$.

Note that $40\leq c\leq 0$. So, there are $21$ solutions for the first equation, and similarly $11$ solutions for the second equation. Since each such $(a,c)$ and each $(b,d)$ gives you a solution, the total number of solutions is $21\times 11=231$.

This completes the answer.

Answer (score 2):

One can consider separately the problem of finding pairs $(\alpha, \beta)$ and $(\gamma, \delta)$ such that

- $2^{40}=2^{2\alpha} 2^\beta$
- $5^{20}=5^{2\gamma} 5^\delta$

Then the number of possible pairs $(n,m)$ is the number of possible pairs $(\alpha, \beta)$ *times* the number of possible pairs $(\gamma, \delta)$.

Now, the problem is only to solve

- $40=2 \alpha + \beta$ and
- $20 = 2 \gamma + \delta.$

Answer (score 2):

Using Hagen von Eitzen comment/hint (and the fundamental theorem of arithmetic),

$\quad m$  can be just an arbitrary divisor of $20^{10}$ (and then $n$ is uniquely determined)

($m$ must divide $20^{10}$ but if $m$ is an arbitrary divisor then we can use $n$ to bring 'things up to snuff')

we start off by writing

$\quad 20^{10} = 2^{20}\cdot 5^{10}$

and see that the positive $(m,n)$ solutions is given by

$\tag {Answer} 21 \times 11 = 231$

Answer (score 0):

$m^{2}n=20^{20}$ means $n$ is a square too i.e. $n=n_{1}^{2}$. Therefore the equation becomes $mn_{1}=20^{10}$ and you see that $m$ is any factor of $2^{10}$.